# Java Deprecated Class using a Deprecated Class -- Can I turn off the compiler warning?

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-warnings

I am working on deprecating a set of Java classes so they aren't used anymore. I don't want to turn off the compiler warnings for deprecated usage, but I'm finding that if one of my deprecated classes imports another deprecated class I get a warning on that, too. I don't want to modify the code I'm deprecating, but I also don't want the warning for those cases. Is there a way to (a) annotate / comment the code to disable the warning (b) turn off compiler warnings in these cases? I'm using NetBeans, so if there is a NetBeans specific way, that works, too.

Here is a quick example:

First class:

```
/**
 * @deprecated No longer in use.
 **/
@Deprecated
public class OldSubClass {
}
```

Second class:

```
import com.old.package.OldSubClass; // Don't want this to create a warning

/**
 * @deprecated No longer in use.
 **/    
@Deprecated
public class OldClass {
       // code that makes use of OldSubClass that I don't want to change ...
       // Any methods that use OldSubClass are also deprecated ...
}
```

Okay, this is the bare minimum that allows me to reproduce the problem (even with @SupressWarnings turned on:

Mother class:

```
import another.pack.ChildClass;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MotherClass {
}
```

Child class:

```
package another.pack;

/**
 * @deprecated
 */
public class ChildClass {
}
```

Note that it is the JavaDoc @deprecated tag that even allows the compiler to throw the warning. If I only use the @Deprecated annotation, I never get the warning (even without the supress).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858021/suppress-deprecated-import-warning-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this other annotation :

> @SuppressWarnings(“deprecation”)

You place this annotation in the mother class only. You will keep the warning when importing the OldClass but the "recursive warning" for the OldSubClass will be ignored.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work on the import. I see that it does work on the methods themselves, though, so it's helpful from that perspective.

Comment: By "mother class" in this example, that would be OldClass, correct? If I put the suppress in there at the class level, the warning for the import still comes up.

Comment: It will work if you put the annotation at the class level (and not on the methods).

Comment: Right, I see what you're saying, and I'll do that. It seems like the class level SuppressWarnings should turn the warning off, though.

Comment: Can you show me an example that you have working. If I put it at the class level, I still get the warning.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans uses javac (from JDK 7) to determine when and where to show warnings like this, so anything that works with `jdk7/bin/javac` should work in the IDE's editor just the same way.

Comment: Made an edit to the original question to show the smallest example where I still get a warning even if I have the @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") turned on. This is the exact warning in the compile logs:

    ...\src\java\MotherClass.java:1: warning: [deprecation] another.pack.ChildClass in another.pack has been deprecated
    import another.pack.ChildClass;

Comment: I also get the same warning when using the java 1.6.0_18 javac command (with -Xlint:deprecated), so it's not just NetBeans.

Comment: Hate to keep adding to this one, but using just the javac compiler, I also get the warning if the suppress is on in the MotherClass and if the ChildClass has the @Deprecated annotation, and no JavaDoc tag. (I don't get the warning in NetBeans under that construct, though.)

Comment: Try using the fully-qualified name of a deprecated class rather than importing it. In some situations this is enough for @SuppressWarnings to work the way you expect. But be aware that there are known bugs in javac's treatment of @SW("deprecation") related to when it resolves symbols versus when it processes the annotation.

Comment: Thanks. That is the way I went, and I got the exceptions out of the way with minor code changes. Certainly, from what I'm seeing there are some issues with the suppress, but for me, it's more a curiosity now.