# Ignore Deprecated Type Warnings on import Statement

Tags: java

I'm importing a class which has been deprecated, which I'm forced to use.

I want to suppress the deprecated error using the `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` annotation.

As per the comment on that annotation:

> As a matter of style, **programmers should always use this annotation on
>   the most deeply nested element where it is effective.** If you want to
>   suppress a warning in a particular method, you should annotate that
>   method rather than its class.

So I clearly don't want to annotate the class and thus suppress deprecation warnings on **any** type my class uses, but I also would like to use the `import` statement to avoid typing out the fully qualified type name, which spans my entire monitor, on each use of the deprecated class.

I think I want to do something like annotating the `import` statement with `@SuppressWarnings` (NOT POSSIBLE) or specifying in the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation which type to ignore warnings for (e.g. `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation", "fully.qualified.type.name")`.

I want to indicate to the compiler "it's okay if I use this one, and only this one, deprecated class, referenced by its Simple Name, anywhere within this other class, and any other deprecated classes I reference you should let me know about".

Is there anything like this available?

Comment: It's fully qualified name spans the entire monitor? I wonder why it was depricated...

Comment: It's a big project...which should probably be split into several smaller projects, but that's not my department.

Comment: Are you just annoyed by the compiler warning?

Comment: does @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") work if you put it right above the import statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858021/suppress-deprecated-import-warning-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450356/java-deprecated-class-using-a-deprecated-class-can-i-turn-off-the-compiler-wa

Comment: It's not a duplicate of either of those.  This is a more specific, and entirely different question.

Comment: I don't want to leave warnings hanging around for non-issues if I can help it.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858021/suppress-deprecated-import-warning-in-java

Answer (score 4):

A way to work around this would be to do the following, assuming you can extend the Deprecated class.

```
import comp.DeprecatedClass;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation") public class MyDeprecatedClass extends DeprecatedClass{ }
```

Then you can use your version without having to worry about warnings.

Comment: I suppose this is an option, provided the class isn't final and you don't mind adding a new layer of class hierarchy.  Seems like a rather extreme solution to me though.
Also: if you do this, nothing stops you from incorrectly re-using the MyDeprecatedClass elsewhere and not seeing the warning messages.

Comment: When using Eclipse, I can hover over MyDeprecatedClass it will show "@SuppressWarnings(value={"deprecation"})" so it does give you an indication that you are suppressing it in a subtle way. While I agree this is extreme, you could get away with doing this inside of where you want to use it: 
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation") private class MyDeprecatedClass extends comp.DeprecatedClass{ } 

Unfortunately, this isn't a pretty work around.