# Android Studio ignore deprecated

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, deprecated

I moved my Eclispe project to Android Studio, but it outputs a lot of deprecated errors when built. I tried some methods, but they don't work.

[image]

Comment: I have tried the method like @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")   and linterror abort,but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Try placing this at the top of the methods:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
```

**Example**

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void testMethod(){
...
}
```

For a brief explaination go to this link:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397996/what-is-suppresswarningsdeprecation-and-unused-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921774/how-to-avoid-deprecation-warnings-when-suppresswarningsdeprecation-doesnt)

Update:

It seems that there is also some known issues with deprecations. You might want to read this for more info:

[stackoverflow.com/questions/26921774/how-to-avoid-deprecation-warnings-when-suppresswarningsdeprecation-doesnt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921774/how-to-avoid-deprecation-warnings-when-suppresswarningsdeprecation-doesnt)