# Android @SuppressWarnings at statement-level, rather than method-level

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-lint, deprecation-warning

TL;DR: Can Android's `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`, or similar, be applied to a single statement, rather than an entire method?

I have a method `myMethod` that uses deprecated method `ImageView.setAlpha()`:

```
public void myMethod(ImageView icon) { icon.setAlpha(0xFF); }
```

To avoid use of the deprecated method in *Jelly Bean* and subsequent releases, whilst providing backward compatibility, method `myMethod` can be rewritten as follows:

```
public void myMethod(ImageView icon) { 
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT 
                                >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
     icon.setImageAlpha(0xFF);
  else 
     icon.setAlpha(0xFF);
}
```

Moreover, command line warnings generated by Gradle/Lint can be suppressed by prepending method `myMethod` with `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`. But, that suppresses all deprecated warnings generated by method `myMethod`, rather than just the single warning generated by statement `icon.setAlpha(0xFF)`.

*Can I suppress the single deprecation warning generated by statement `icon.setAlpha(0xFF)`, rather than suppressing all deprecation warnings generated by method `myMethod`?*

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it as follows if you are using Android Studio:

```
 //noinspection deprecation
 icon.setAlpha(0xFF);
```

**For your future reference:** The correct format can be easily generated in Android-Studio as follows:

1. Press alt+Enter on the statement which is throwing warning.
2. Then Expand the option `Deprecated API usage` options
3. Click on `Suppress for statement`

**Following Image shows the process:**

[image]

In your case since you are not using IDE:

- Unfortunately there is no direct way to achieve it at method body level. Since you have already moved the deprecated part in individual method and marked it with `@SuppressWarnings` this should be best you can achieve.
- There are some posts which claim to have solved it by using fully qualified class name instead of `import`. But looks like the issue has been fixed in Java 9. Since current popular java version for android is 8.x this should help in short term. You can refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858021/suppress-deprecated-import-warning-in-java) for more details

Comment: That doesn't work, I get `warning: [deprecation] setAlpha(int) in ImageView has been deprecated`. Perhaps I need to do something else since I work from the command line, rather than an IDE (e.g., Android-Studio).