# Is there a global setting in the Java Compiler to disable deprecation for String.formatted()?

Tags: java, java-13

The method `String.formatted()` is a new feature in Java 13 introduced together with text blocks and can be used instead of `String.format(templateString, replacement1, replacement2, ...)`.

The compiler issues a jarring warning when using this method because it might be removed again in future versions (but it could also stay).

Is there a way to specifically disable this compiler warning without annotating each usage with `@SuppressWarnings("removal")` or disabling all deprecation warnings as java compiler parameter?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858021/suppress-deprecated-import-warning-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can suppress warnings bypassing compiler argument. In your case, you can use `-Xlint`. -Xlint can be used with different properties.

**-Xlint**
Enable all recommended warnings.

**-Xlint:all**
Enable all recommended warnings.

**-Xlint:none**
Disable all warnings.

**-Xlint:name**
Enable warning name. See the section Warnings That Can Be Enabled or Disabled with -Xlint Option for a list of warnings you can enable with this option.

**-Xlint:-name**
Disable warning name. See the section Warnings That Can Be Enabled or Disabled with -Xlint Option for a list of warnings you can disable with this option.

For more info please go through java [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can add `-Xlint:-removal` parameter to `javac` command line and instead of warning you will get a note message per class:

> Note: MyClass.java uses or overrides a deprecated API that is marked for removal.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:removal for details.

I don't think there is an option to specify this just for `String.formatted()`, it's global.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: **don't do this**. If your project cares about deprecation warnings, you probably shouldn't be using preview features like `String.formatted()`.

In fact, the method **will be removed** in Java 14, at least if you don't use `--enable-preview`.

Your code will not compile if you use this method without `--enable-preview` because the method will be annotated with `@jdk.internal.PreviewFeature` (instead of `@Deprecated`).